# Which is grammatically appropriate: what you brought me or what you brought for me?

Tags: american-english

In informal US English, is the "for" optional in a sentence like this:

> I want to know what you brought (for) me.

Is it written like this, instead:

> I want to know what you brought me.

Comment: Both are fine. Bring me is the most common. I'm not sure one can say that bring for a person is informal US English.

Comment: **brought for you** and **brought you** are both idiomatic. There's nothing especially formal or informal about them, they're neutral. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22what%20i%20brought%20for%20you%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en